# A bit misunderstanding about odr-used definition

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

The definition of the odr-used variable is given as follows:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   ex is odr-used unless x satisfies the requirements for appearing in a
>   constant expression (5.19) and, if x is an object, ex is an element of
>   the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

As far as I understood `ex` can be any expression containing `x` as a potentially evaluated operand, say, `x++` or

```
int foo(int);
int x;

//...

x+=foo(x);
```

But I didn't understand what is just `e` in that case.

Comment: `ex` is an expression consisting of just `x`. `e` is an expression of which `ex` is a sub-expression. Note how the standard says that the name `x` appears **as** an expression `ex`, not **in**.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you! BTW, couldn't you explain what does the following mean: _An assignment operator function in a class is odr-used by an implicitly-defined copy-assignment or move-assignment function for another class as specified in 12.8._ I'm confused by _function for another class_. What that got to do with the function for another class? For example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd0228fe1f2fc8a1 .

Comment: Simply said, if the class is used for sub-objects (base or member) in another class, and that other classes corresponding special-member is ODR-used, the classes special-member is ODR-used too.

Comment: Not just any random another class of course - a class that has an object of your class as a member, or as a base class subobject, or similar. Details are in **12.8** that the passage you cite refers you to.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I went over the section 12.8 but couldn't find the definition of odr-used. I found notes _[ Note: The copy/move constructor is implicitly defined even if the implementation elided its odr-use (3.2, 12.2). —end note ]_ and _A copy/move assignment operator for a class X that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used (3.2) (e.g., when it is selected by overload resolution to assign to an object of
its class type)_. But they refers to the odr-used definition...

Comment: **12.8** doesn't define odr-used. It explains the circumstances under which an implicitly-defined assignment operator of one class may call an assignment operator of another class. Then, whenever the former is odr-used, the latter is, too.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hmm.... OK, thank you again. But you said it __may__ call, but I thinkt it shouldn't. For instance, is in the following example copy-assignment operator odr-used http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6fb1901dd868be3

Comment: In that example, neither of the two operators is odr-used. Therefore, you could omit their bodies, and the program would still compile and link.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm totally confused. _An assignment operator function in a class is odr-used by an implicitly-defined
copy-assignment or move-assignment function for another class as specified in 12.8._ Might it mean if the implicitly-defined operator is odr-used then the assignment operator in the class is odr-used by the implicitly-defined operator? For instance http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd3d5043b3fa6ade . Is my understanding correct now?

Comment: Yes, in your new example, implicitly defined `B::operator=` is odr-used because `main` is calling it; and explicitly defined `A::operator=` is odr-used because `B::operator=` is calling it.